# Scrollable canvasjs chart

Tags: javascript, charts, canvasjs

I'm trying to make scrollable vertical canvasjs chart.

This is html:

```
<div style="height:300px; width: 100%; overflow-y:scroll">
    <div id="dataContainer" style="width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

This is javascript:

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("dataContainer",
{  
    title:{
        text: data['name']            
    },
    axisY:{
       gridThickness: 0,
     },           
    data: [{
        animationEnabled: false,
        indexLabelPlacement: "inside",
        indexLabelFontColor: "white",
        indexLabelFontWeight: 600,
        indexLabelFontFamily: "Verdana",
        type: "bar",
        dataPoints: dataPoints[0]
    },
    {
        animationEnabled: false,
        indexLabelPlacement: "inside",
        indexLabelFontColor: "white",
        indexLabelFontWeight: 600,
        indexLabelFontFamily: "Verdana",
        type: "bar",
        dataPoints: dataPoints[1]
    }           
    ]
});

chart.render();
```

This is the result:

[image]

I have added dataPointWidth:

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("dataContainer",
{  
    dataPointWidth: 20, 
    title:{
        text: data['name']            
    },
 ...
};
```

This is the result (looks like a bug):

[image]

How to make chart with scroller and columns of normal size?

Comment: You have to increase chart/container height as you increase of dataPointWidth.

Comment: Sanjoy: Thank you. But this is workaround, because I don't know its height, it depends on chart data. I can set very big height, but scroller will be wrong.

Comment: And it doesn't help.

Comment: By default, chart automatically calculates dataPointWidth to give a nice view. But in your case, you have set dataPointWidth to a value too large. So, in-order to show all the dataPoints in the given height, they overlap with each other.

For simple understanding, consider this example: You have a container height of 100px and inside that you have placed 2 bar. If each bar width is 60px, they have to overlap by 20px.

Comment: Sanjoy: and I want to avoid this. My charts can be very large and when I set inner div height to 30 000 px  the canvasjs chart throws an error.

Comment: Maybe you can tell me about other js chart library without bugs?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vaeq29kz/
This is how chart will look if you set inner div height to 3000px. You must have done anything wrong for which you are getting error.

Answer (score -1):

[google charts library](https://developers.google.com/chart/) works fine.